# Android stops sending out BLE beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

I am trying to implement room-level presence detection. I have esp32 devices in each room, all reporting to mqtt, and it works beautifully with Tile transmitters.  I am also trying to detect my Android phones but they consistently stop transmitting after a short period of time. I am using a Pixel 6 Pro running Android 13 with the March 5 2023 update.  I first tried the Home Assistant BLE Transmitter sensor that is built in to the larger phone app.  It initially works, but only sends 2, sometimes 3 messages.  The status continues to say "transmitting".  The app does not terminate.  Turning the transmitter off and on results in an additional 1 message; changing one of the parameters, such as transmit power does the same thing.  I initially thought it might be an issue with the Home Assistant app, so I tried BeaconScope but it behaves exactly the same way.  Each of the apps is exempt from battery management, and each of them has all of the requested permissions.

I have repeatedly tried the two apps, monitoring with MQTT Explorer.  I expected to see regular transmissions from the Pixel but did not.  I did consistently see regular transmissions from 4 Tile dongles.

Comment: If you run BeaconScope on two phones (one transmitting one receiving) and you leave both in the foreground,  does the receiving phone detect the transmitting phone for many minutes at a time?

Comment: You were right.  I installed BeaconScope on my Chromebook, and it proved that the Pixel was correctly transmitting beacons from both HA BLE sensor and BeaconScope while espresense was not reporting these packets.  I just saw a similar complaint on the espresense Github site from the owner of a OnePlus 8 pro.  Do you think these 2 phones could be doing something with the packets that is causing espresense not to see them?  It appears to be seeing everything else that it is supposed to, and consistently.  Thanks!

Comment: I do not think receiving devices can do anything to alter BLE packets in flight.  I would focus troubleshooting on Expresense reception.  To simplify the problem, perhaps experiment with one simple transmitter  and the Expresense scanner and make sure you can get it to detect reliably before using it in a project.

Comment: I've figured it out, and it is definitely an espresense bug. It is Android-related, but not Pixel per se. Espresense correctly logs (and sends to MQTT) the first Android iBeacon, and any subsequent beacons that use the same MAC address. However, if the MAC address changes, no subsequent iBeacons are logged for that iBeacon. That explains why "1 or 2 packets" might initially be received. Sometimes Android sends the first 2 packets before it changes the MAC address. David, I deeply appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Great finding!  You might consider making this you own answer to the question so it could more easily help others who run into the same problem.

Comment: Related question: in BeaconScope I am trying eddystone because espresense appears to process those beacons correctly. However, BeaconScope only sends beacons while in the foreground, and there is no permission request for allow location all the time. I wonder if BeaconScope needs the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.

Comment: Troubleshooting beacon transmission in the background is certainly a different topic worthy of an independent question.  Please post and I will answer in more detail.  If you do, please be aware that BeaconScope is designed to transmit in the background and does so on Google Pixel and Android Open Source devices.  So what you are describing may be a OEM-specific issue.